# Python Boolean: Why there is a differences between a class & class instance in Evaluate Values and Variables?

Tags: python

In python, we all know that there are not many values that evaluates to False, except empty values, such as `(), [], {}, "", the number 0, and the value None`. And of course the value False evaluates to False. But here i have some code that i could not understand why there is a differences in  `print()` function output. here is the code:

```
class myclass():
   def __len__(self):
      return 0 # even return False will give us the same answer.
myobj = myclass()
print(bool(myobj)) # False
print(bool(myclass())) # False
# this is an instance of a class
print(bool(myclass)) # True
#this is a class
```

so now why `bool(myobj)` not the same as `bool(myclass)` while `myobj = myclass()`?

I expect the output is `False` for both, but the actual output is `False` and `True`.

Comment: `myobj` and `myclass` are completely different things. Why would you expect them to have the same truth value?

Comment: Besides the answers others have posted, `__len__` isn't the best method to override to set an object's truth value; you should use `__bool__` in Python 3, or `__nonzero__` in Python 2—`__len__` should only be used for some form of length or size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `myclass()` and `myclass` are differrent. `myclass()` is class instance and `myclass` is an object like int, like anything else. In your question, `myobj` equals to `myclass()` and myobjs evaluates to false because of `return 0` but `myclass` evaluates to true because class's boolean values are true.

Comment: i miss this '()' so the output was True, thank you @marceline. I don't know why there is down votes for my question while its clear there is a problem in that code.

Answer (score 0):

Because `myclass` and `myclass()` are not the same. `myclass` is a class, `myclass()` is an instance of that class. `bool(myobj)` and `bool(myclass())` will both return `False`.